# Design pattern that builds different step of execution at runtime

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a class that has N methods for internal use and these N methods can be combined in random sequence inside of other execute methods.

```py
class DummyOperator:
    def step_1(self):
        pass

    .....
    
    def step_n(self):
        pass
    
    def execute_1(self):
        self.step_1()
        self.step_5()
        self.step_9()
        self.step_2()
    
    .....
    
    def execute_m(self):
        self.step_7()
        self.step_6()
```

In some other file, there is call of one of these execute methods depending on cofig file

```py
main.py

conf_value = get_value_from_config()
obj = DummyOperator()
execute_method = None
if conf_value == 'param_1':
    execute_method = obj.execute_1
....
if conf_value == 'param_m':
    execute_method = obj.execute_m
    
execute_method()
```

The problem that amount of execute methods is big and growing fast but decomposition of this class is not convenient because these N methods suite good for this logic entity. Also the system have bunch of such classes.
Can you please tell what is better approach to design such architecture and how dynamically can execute method of Operator class can be built at runtime?

Comment: Use lists and dictionaries rather than numbered functions - https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-use-strings-to-call-functions-methods

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer Question not in how to call this functions but how dynamically can execute method of Operator class can be built at runtime

Comment: `getattr(obj, 'execute_' + x)` as that link shows

Comment: The question is how to reduce M execute methods of Operator class to one execute method that operate as expected according to config file.

Comment: How about `def execute(steps)`, and pass in a numbered list from your config file that tells which step functions to run? In other words, why do you actually need M execute methods?